# ubuntu 16.04 install loses cursor and keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Since installing 16.04 LTS, we can only use the computer for a short time before the cursor is gone and no keyboard input, including arrow and TAB, will work. Sometimes the cursor is gone before we can even log in. In addition, logging in as a user gives us a blank colored screen with only the words Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in the lower left corner. We can only get a graphic interface by logging as guest, then switching to user.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say about the keyboard though but you can bring back the cursor pretty easily. 
Open terminal (CTR + ALT + T)

type $ ls
After 2 -3 sec the cursor should come back.